# Rodar dois serviços no mesmo domínio em portas distintas

Tags: nginx

Preciso configurar uma aplicação que possui dois serviços distintos rodando na porta 80 e outro na 8080, porém no mesmo domínio. Pergunto a vocês se é possível e como poderia configurá-los dessa forma?

Exemplo:

`meuunicodominio.com.br:80` caminho: `/var/www/appfrontend`

`meuunicodominio.com.br:8080` caminho: `/var/www/appbackend`

A questão para essa façanha é o uso de duas tecnologias, na 80 roda PHP e na 8080 roda node.js, não tenho opção de criar subdomínios ou adicionar outro domínio, no máximo posso usar o IP da máquina pra apontar o backend.

Comment: sem acesso a modificar a configuração do nginx não é possível.

Comment: Eu tenho acesso root ao server. O problema que não posso usar outro domínio, por isso tenho que se virar com o mesmo usando portas diferentes para duas apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na documentação há exemplos de como configurar: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Exemplo de configuração:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  foo.bar  www.foo.bar;
    root         /var/www/foo.bar/
}

server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  bar.foo  www.bar.foo;
    root         /var/www/bar.foo/
}
```

Comment: Obrigado camarada, funcionou!